# How to backup Minion Rush?

Tags: android, despicable-me-minion-rush

I wonder, there's an option to sign in with Google or Facebook account, mostly this tracks achievements which *that* much important to me. I have some costumes in the game that I won or bought with the tokens from challenges.

I'd like to know where does the game saves the data about what costumes I have unlocked, how much coins and tokens I have and so on. I guess achievements are logged at Google/Facebook database, but I'm not sure if the game data are saved on the device only or on the server too.

**Example:**

I probably have a game id which I think is assigned for Google/Facebook account after I sign in. If I backup with Titanium(rooted) data + apk, will I have a mirror of the game on another device, or does it *need* G/F account to get the data. Or something else?

I'd gladly try installing from Titanium backup, but I don't have spare device with me and I don't feel like reinstalling the app if I could lose data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bricked & unbricked my phone with a special effect of wiping everything, such a pleasant experience.

**TLDR**: Backup is on server. Titanium shouldn't be necessary.

Backup is (at least) on the Google Play. The backup on Google Play includes (july 16):

- coins
- tokens
- costumes
- event tracking (+ item counting)
- achievements
- unopened capsules

Don't know about other important stuff or if it's available via Facebook account link, but it probably is.

I logged with the same account and didn't change the generated name (not neccessary I think) and then it provided a *merge* between the accounts. The merge was available ***after*** the tutorial game where it shows the game controlling.

**Without account:** The data are stored locally probably in `/data/<game>` or `/data/data/<game>`, so backup available only with `root`.